# Como puedo adicionar a los elementos [i][j] al lado de la diagonal de la matriz en python

Tags: python, numpy

Tengo la siguiente función:

```py
#Matriz con la diagonal
def Q_diag(n,l,mu):
    lis = list(range(n,0,-1))  # lista que parte en n, termina en 1
    mlis = np.array(lis)       #la pasamos a vector
    llu = -(mlis * l + mu)     #multiplicamos por lambda y sumamos mu
    llu[0] = -n*l              #recordamos que el primer valor, es solo -n*lambda
    llu[n-1] = -mu             #el valor de (n,n) es -mu
    mat = llu*np.identity(n)
    return mat
```

Que me retorna una matriz de nxn con una diagonal con determinados valores (y el resto de elementos de la matriz son ceros).

Mi intención es adicionar elementos al costado derecho de la diagonal. Estos elementos los tengo en la siguiente función:

```py
#Vector con los elementos a la derecha de la diagonal
def Q_post(n,l,mu):
    lisp = list(range(n,1,-1))
    vlisp = np.array(lisp)
    lamb = vlisp*l
    return lamb
```

Cómo puedo recorrer la matriz?, tal que si:

```
mat[fila][columna] = mat[fila][fila+1]

#reemplazo el valor por:
mat[fila][columna] = lamb[fila]
```

Y de esta forma me quede la matriz `mat` con elementos al costado derecho de la diagonal?

Ejemplo: Q_diag(6,1,10) debería retornar la siguiente matriz (mat):

```
[[ -6.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.]
 [ -0. -15.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.]
 [ -0.  -0. -14.  -0.  -0.  -0.]
 [ -0.  -0.  -0. -13.  -0.  -0.]
 [ -0.  -0.  -0.  -0. -12.  -0.]
 [ -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0. -10.]]
```

y Q_post(6,1,10) el siguiente vector:

```
[6 5 4 3 2]
```

Mi intención es que en la posición mat[1][2] = lamb[0] ; mat[2][3] = lamb[1] ... así hasta mat[4][5] (cuarta fila, 5ta columna) sea rellenada por el ultimo elemento del vector lamb (lamb[4]).

De esta forma la matriz quede:

```
 [[ -6.  6  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.]
 [ -0. -15.  5  -0.  -0.  -0.]
 [ -0.  -0. -14.  4  -0.  -0.]
 [ -0.  -0.  -0. -13.  3  -0.]
 [ -0.  -0.  -0.  -0. -12.  2]
 [ -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0. -10.]]
```

Y así generalizar para matrices con los parametros n,l y mu

Comment: he creado una matriz de 3x3, al ejecutar tu otra función me retorna un lista de 2 elementos, ¿Cómo quieres rellenar el lado derecho que son 3 elementos con solo 2?, sería bueno que pongas lo que esperas como resultado

Comment: Como Q_diag retorna una matriz de nxn, y Q_post retorna un vector con n-1 elementos, quisiera reemplazar los valores del [i][j] inmediatamente al lado derecho del [i][i], por los elementos del vector lambda que retorna Q_post

Comment: El primer elemento se encuentra en la posición `[0][0]`  en el caso de una matriz 3x3 al lado tiene 2 elementos con 0, en la segunda `[1][1]` se tiene un solo elemento al lado derecho y en la tercera ninguna

Comment: Pero ya entendí lo que quieres hacer  en un momento te doy una respuesta

Answer (score 1):

lo más fácil que puedes hacer es una función que reciba como parámetros, la matriz y los valores de la lista, la diagonal siempre será `[i][i]` y si quieres cambiar su valor derecho, será `[i][i+1]`

```py
def cambiar(matrix, values):
    for i in range(len(matrix[0])-1): #restamos 1 por que el ultimo no necesita ser cambaido
        matrix[i][i+1] = values[i] #cambiamos el valor
    return matrix
```

**probamos**

```
matriz = Q_diag(6,1,10)
valores = Q_post(6,1,10)

nueva = cambiar(matriz,valores)
```

**resultado**

```
array([[ -6.,   6.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.],
       [ -0., -15.,   5.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.],
       [ -0.,  -0., -14.,   4.,  -0.,  -0.],
       [ -0.,  -0.,  -0., -13.,   3.,  -0.],
       [ -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0., -12.,   2.],
       [ -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0., -10.]])
```